# Share entered values while sharing a link

Tags: javascript, html, ios, http

here is my problem: It would be great if users could not only share the link to my website, but also the values they entered there. So far, so good.

First try: simply submit values by GET.

Does not work because: if the URL is

```
domain.com?param1=a&param2=b
```

then simply the part before the ? will be shared (at least on iPhones, but that's bad.) So they just share

```
domain.com
```

and no parameters are sent. (Google told me the same without giving me a proper workaround idea.)

Okay. Second try: Some workaround involving .htaccess and history.pushstate. It worked quite well, but history.pushstate does not seem to affect the shared URL on iPhones either.

That's bad so far. Does maybe anyone have an idea what to use to solve my problem? Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

btW: I found a solution by myself:

The shared URL is the one set in the

```
<link rel="canonical" href="domain.com?param1=a&param2=b">
```

So if I share, the parameters are ignored if they are not found in the canonical link.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct to share `domain.com?param1=a&param2=b`. GET Parameters will be maintained.